# Adjust text preview width and color in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I inserted the executable code below that shows centered text that takes up the entire width of the page. But my idea is to reduce this width. So, the idea is reduce the widht, to leave the text centered (it's already) and justified. If possible I would also like the text "Project Description" to be blue in color.

Thank you very much!

Executable code below

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                             
                                   br(),
                                   hr(),
                               
                                   h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
                                   style="text-align:center"),
                                   hr(),
                                   h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                                   style="text-align:center"),
                                   h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                                      style="text-align:center")))
                                   
                                  
                                

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(
  title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
  
  tabPanel("",
           
           br(),
           hr(),
           
           h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
              style="text-align:center; color: blue;"),
           hr(),
           div(
             style = "width: 75%; margin: auto;",
             h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                style="text-align:center"),
             h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                style="text-align:center"))
  )
)




server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom css class and apply it.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("",
                                 tags$style(".align_class {
                                             margin-left: 80px;
                                             margin-right: 80px;
                                             text-align:center;
                                            }"),
                                 br(),
                                 hr(),
                                 div(class = 'align_class', 
                                 h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
                                    style="color:blue"),
                                 hr(),
                                 h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                                    style="text-align:center"),
                                 h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum")))))




server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]